# Effect of mass of the virtual particle in a one-loop Feynman diagram

Tags: mass, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, fermions

We have a one-loop Feynman diagram, say a Penguin diagram. Assume that we have a virtual fermion in the loop that is different from the particles represented by the external lines. If I increase the mass of this virtual fermion (and keep everything else fixed), what will happen to the cross-section? Will it increase or decrease?

In light of Connor's comment, let me make the question more specific. In the process given in the diagram with muon energy of the order of tens of GeVs interacting with a fixed nucleus, what will happen to cross-section when the mass of the hypothetical fermion $\nu_i$ is increased (assuming that this mass is much above the muon beam energy)?[image: Penguin diagram]

Comment: You cannot increase the mass of a virtual particle. The four vector of virtual particles is under the limits of the interaction  https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/lectures/partIIIparticles/Handout3_2009.pdf and it is the four vector length that gives the mass to the virtual particle. see the feynman diagram here page 12

Comment: Much of our knowledge about particle physics comes from resonances that occur when the center of mass energy $\sqrt{s}$ is close to a virtual particle mass $m$. A resonance like this decays on *either side*. So there is clearly no blanket statement we can make about how the cross section changes when we increase $m$. Increases and decreases are both possible.

Comment: @annav What I meant was the unknown mass of a hypothetical particle.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thanks for the insight. I have edited the question to make it more specific. Here, when I increase $m$ doesn't the situation move further away from resonance, so that the cross-section will decrease?

Comment: That sounds right to me. I think a good point of comparison is a beta decay where internal W bosons are more massive than any other scale. In that case, the amplitude is approximately proportional to $G_F \sim M_W^{-2}$ which also supports your conclusion.

Comment: you mean change the virtual particle exchanged to one with heavier mass,  which will change the mass in the propagator